# How to identify a pattern containing nested parameters within it

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I'm trying to find some regular expression to use in sed, to enclose a pattern (which might contain nested paramters) with some text.

A basic example would be

```
length(bill_cycle)
```

the regex should give

```
length(cast(bill_cycle as string))
```

Here, we search for it to start with `length(` and we find the closing `)` associated with `length(`. We then replace whatever is in between, in this case , `bill_cycle` with `cast(bill_cycle as string)`

Even if the variable (in this case is `some(somethiing)` ) has nested parameters like

```
length(some(somethiing))
```

the regex should give

```
length(cast(some(somethiing) as string))
```

I'm open to any unix scripting or other commands which would work. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that your `length()` text is wrapped in parentheses, as in `print(length(something))`?

Comment: that might be possible.... i needed to change the format from normal length(variable) to casting the variable inside it as string..... i needed to do this for dozens of queries, so i thought a simple script would work

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -MText::Balanced=extract_bracketed \
     -ne 'if (/length(\(.*)/) {
              ($arg) = (extract_bracketed(($1 =~ /\((.*)\)/)[0]))[1];
              print "length(cast($arg as string))\n";
          } else { print }' -- input.file > output.file
```

It uses the core module [Text::Balanced](http://p3rl.org/Text::Balanced) that extracts substrings with balanced delimiters from strings.

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl` and recursive matching:

```bsh
$ cat ip.txt
length(bill_cycle)
length(some(somethiing))

$ perl -pe 's/length(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))++)\))/length(cast($2 as string))/' ip.txt 
length(cast(bill_cycle as string))
length(cast(some(somethiing) as string))
```

See https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html to know how the recursion works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk script that uses no pattern matching for the parentheses, but counts them. It will also match more than one occurences per line.

```bsh
BEGIN { 
    p = "length"
}

{
    row = $0
    while (row ~ p"\\(") {
        # get the substring from pattern to the end of the line
        # and split to array with closing parenthesis separator

        x = substr(row, index(row,p) + length(p))
        split(x, a, ")")
        res = p

        # loop for array items and append them to substring
        # until we have a string with same number of
        # opening and closing parentheses.

        for (i=1;i<=length(a);i++) {

            res = res a[i] (i==length(a)? "": ")")

            if (gsub(/\(/,"(",res) == gsub(/\)/,")",res)) {
                print res
                break
            }
        }
        
        # will test again the rest of the row
        row = substr(x, length(p))
    }
}
```

Some basic testing

```bsh
> cat file
some text length(a(b)) testing another occurence length(a))
function(length(c(d(e(f(1), 2)))) testinglength(x)
x length(y))
x length(((y))
length(length(1))

> awk -f tst.awk file
length(a(b))
length(a)
length(c(d(e(f(1), 2))))
length(x)
length(y)
length(length(1))
```

Comment: As far as I know, awk does not support PCREs.